# Apache Spark - How to capture all the exceptions and log it or propagate the exceptions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, apache-spark-sql

We are using Spark `1.6.1 Version` and `Scala 2.10` version to write Spark applications.

How can i capture all the exceptions and handle it `[Log it or Propagate it]`? We are using Spark SQL to create `DataFrames` from the source and apply transformations on `DF` and finally write the DF to some database.

Should i go with simple `try catch` or `Scala 2.10 Try, Sucess, Failure`?

If i use Scala 2.10 feature, will it catch all the exceptions (Fatal and Non Fatal)?

Comment: I was wondering this is scala feature.  What is your experience so far(I mean what was working/Not working as expected). I mean have you tried both ? AFAIK question is broad..

Comment: Do you mean you have exceptions on the workers and you want to get them all on the driver?

Comment: Are there any updates? I have exactly the same question, but spark is of v 2.0.2 and scala is 2.11.8.